# Logit prediction withs specified X variable in R

Tags: r, regression

I'm trying to predict the number of vehicles that have a V engine (vs. straight engine) given one specified x-variable wt=2100 (no restiction on disp). So I build the logit model as follow:

`model <- glm(formula= vs ~ wt + disp, data=mtcars, family=binomial)`

But I encounter a problem in using the prediction function. I tried to create a data frame

```
newdata = data.frame(wt = 2.1)
```

and then use the predict() function to calculate the predicted probability.

```
predict(model, newdata, type="response")
```

but I encounter an error: Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'disp' not found.
I know I didn't specify a disp value in the newdata, but my question, what if I only have a specified wt, but don't have a specified disp in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The prediction function simply applies the formula for generating predictions, which in this case is
$$\hat{y} = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-\hat\beta_0 - \hat\beta_1 \text{wt} - \hat\beta_2 \text{disp})}$$
Without a provided value for `disp`, how can the formula be applied? What should go in place of $disp$? It can't be 0; `disp` may not even be able to take on a value of 0. If you build a model with a set of predictors, you need to supply all those predictors to get a predicted value. If you don't have `disp` available, you can either fit a model without it and supply your desired value of `wt` alone, or you can use some method to choose one or values of `disp` to supply to the formula.